# Can you show me an alternative to these lengthy if else statements?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, range

I'm trying to create code that takes the number of items that a customer has bought, then print out how much will be discounted.

```
1-3 items purchased will get no discount
4-6 items purchased will get 5% discount
7-10 items purchased will get 10% discount
11 or more items purchased will get a 15% discount
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you. Here is the code that i created.

```
package discount;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Discount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the number of items: ");
        int quantity = input.nextInt();
                
        int[] discount = {0, 5, 10, 15};
        
        if (quantity >= 1 && quantity < 4) {
            System.out.print("no discount");
        } else if (quantity >= 4 && quantity < 7) {
            System.out.print(discount[1] + "% discount");
        } else if (quantity >= 7 && quantity < 11) {
            System.out.print(discount[2] + "% discount");
        } else if (quantity >= 11) {
            System.out.print(discount[3] + "% discount");
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, a switch statement would work. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html.  If there were too many case labels to enumerate, then the `TreeMap` class is an alternative.

Comment: I agree with the above, but that code above is not yet what I would categorize as "lengthy". It's not well-formatted, but I can fix that for you.

Comment: Agreed.  It is doubtful that it is worth the effort to make this code shorter.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Can you teach me how i can make it well-formatted?

Comment: A simplification would be to remove the `discount` array, and use literals in the bodies of the if statements instead. This has the advantage that you can immediately see what quantity is associated with which discount, and removes the possibility of having an array index in an if statement which doesn't exist in `discount`. However this change conflicts with the goal of learning Java, and I hope you did get, and fix, at least one `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while working on this code!

Comment: "Can you teach me how i can make it well-formatted?" - Look at the edit history and compare ...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to apply decomposition by extracting the code that is responsible for calculating discounts and printing messages into separate methods. It will make your code cleaner even without switch expressions.

**1. Calculate discount:**

```
public static int getDiscount(int items) {
    return switch(items) {
        case 0, 1, 2, 3 -> 0;
        case 4, 5, 6 -> 5;
        case 7, 8, 9, 10 -> 10;
        default -> 15;
    };
}
```

**2. Print the message:**

```
public static void printMessage(int discount) {
    switch(discount) {
        case 0 -> System.out.print("no discount");
        default -> System.out.println(discount + "% discount");
    }
}
```

**3. main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input the number of items: ");
            
    printMessage(getDiscount(input.nextInt()));
}
```

- This code will work with Java 14 onwards

Comment: This won't work with Java 11 or earlier.  (Or on Android).  Switch expressions are a new language feature ...

Comment: That's correct, it'll work only with the latest LTS version of Java

Answer (score 0):

Without Kotlin `when`, Java's `switch` may or may not do what everything you would like. But if you do want to write with `if-else`, it can clean up:

```
if(quantity > 0){ 
    int discount = -1
    if(quantity < 4) discount = 0; 
    else if (quantity < 7) discount = 5; 
    else if (quantity < 11) discount = 10;
    else discount = 15; 
    printDiscountMessage(discount)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
int discountCalculation = (quantity >= 1 && quantity < 4) ?discount[0]: (quantity >= 4 && quantity < 7)?discount[1]: (quantity >= 7 && quantity < 11) ?discount[2]:discount[3];
```